# Ruby do-block, and RestClient

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby.

I noticed that if I do (assume "request" has been defined):

```
RestClient::Request.execute(request) do |response|
  print response
end
```

Then response is empty. But if I do

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(request)
print response
```

Then response has something.

What's the reason why the second one works and the first one doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/w/wgibbs-rest-client-1.0.5/RestClient/Request.html#method-c-execute) for `RestClient::Request.execute` doesn't show it takes a block:

```
def self.execute(args)
        new(args).execute
end
```

It only returns the value returned by calling `execute` on an anonymous instance of RestClient.

Comment: What would it have to say if it were to take a block?

Comment: It would `yield` control to the block somewhere during execution. Since it doesn't, even if you add a block, the code won't try to call it.